# Cannot resolve com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService; Android studio

Tags: android, client, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services, build.gradle

**Edit: I solved this problem:)**
Cause of this error :

1. In the tutorial Implementing GCM Client , there was [link](https://github.com/google/gcm) to download full source code for demo.
2. Downloaded for reference , added google_play_service library in build.gradle.
3. Did some recommended changes like SENDER_ID,SERVER_URL,.. etc
4. Synch the project with gradle and got this error.

How I solved!

1. After lot of google I found that this class is not in google_play_service library but it is in gcm.jar which is deprecated now.
   I dont know why google has given link to old code and explained latest code in the document.
2. Then I include the gcm.jar
3. And the error gone, got push notification:)

Hope this will help to someone who got in this trouble!

**My Old Question**

I am new to android studio. I dont understand build.gradle. Today I was implementing gcm-demo-client following instructions given here https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html 
But when I import it from suggested [open source code](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/) I got below errors.

```
/home/shani/Desktop/gcm-76908409d9d5/samples/gcm-demo-client1/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gcm/demo/app/GCMIntentService.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;
                             ^
  symbol:   class GCMBaseIntentService
  location: package com.google.android.gcm
```

also there are other 25 errors. After some search on Google I found that it is because I had not added google play service library in build.gradle.

Then I added library:
Below is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.android.gcm.demo.app"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
        dependencies {
            compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.+"
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I click on sync now link I got Build Success. But when I try to run on real device above error comes. I dont know what I am doing wrong. Please give me the solution, I really spend two days implementing gcm demo app.

Comment: Hi, thank you for sharing your gained knowledge. If your question is solved, consider adding an answer and accepting it, instead of editing the question.   This does make it more visible for other users

Comment: @Programmer You should really post your solution as an answer and [accept your own answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 4):

This happens if you use the latest, `7.0.0` version. They sliced up the Google Play Services a bit further than in 6.5, due to how there is an upper limit to method count (65536).

Anyways,

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.87'
```

This works with the `GCM` classes the guides mention.

But it also works by updating to the latest

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.0.0'
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is that gradle is not downloading your dependency. I had the same problem but I solved it when I Invalidated cache and restarted android studio. Click on file > invalidate cache/restart

Answer (score 0):

The google play services you are using is outdated use the following lines in your gradle file and then again sync the project with gradle.

```
dependencies {
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
}
```

This will surely remove your error.

Comment: Actually, for me, the error came about from updating to 7.0.0 from `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.87'`

Answer (score 0):

Use this Google Play Services, it's working

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
```

Comment: Isn't this covered by previous answers?